# I'm trying to insert data that I've scrapped off twitter into my postgres database but failing

Tags: python, postgresql, twitter

I'm using snscrape lib to scrape twitter data off twitter. I want to insert this data into my database but I seem to be failing no matter what method I try. when I use a loop and create a sql query after the loop to insert the values 1 by 1. I get an IndexError and a TypeError. When I try to append the data into a list. I can't loop in to each value 1 by 1. Now I'm stuck and don't know what to do.

method 1

```
class Tweet_list():

    def tweets_list1(self):
        dbname = '******'
        user = '******'
        password = '******'
        host = '*******' 
        port = ****
        cur = None
        conn = None
        
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
                dbname = dbname,
                user = user,
                password = password,
                host = host, 
                port = port   
        )
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Machine_twitter')

        create_table =  '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Machine_twitter (
            id      int PRIMARY KEY,
            Tweet   text,
            Tweet_id    int,
            Timestamp   timestamp,
            Replys   int,
            Retweets    int,
            Likes   int,
            Username    char)''' 

        cur.execute(create_table)
        for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:TheHoopCentral').get_items()):
            if i > 5:
                break
            insert_tweet = 'INSERT INTO Machine_twitter (Tweet, Tweet_id, Timestamp, Replys, Retweets, Likes, Username) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s)'
            insert_values = (tweet.content, tweet.id, tweet.date, tweet.replyCount, tweet.retweetCount, tweet.likeCount, tweet.user.username)
            cur.execute(insert_tweet, insert_values)
            
        conn.commit()
        print('completed')

    except Exception as error:
            print(error)  

    finally:
        if cur is not None:
            cur.close()
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

tweets = Tweet_list()
tweets2 = Tweet_list()

tweets2.tweets_list1()
```

error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

method 2

```
def update_list1(self):
        tweets_list2 = []

        for i, tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:TheHoopCentral').get_items()):
            if i > 100:
                break
            tweets_list2.append([tweet.content, tweet.id,tweet.likeCount, tweet.retweetCount, tweet.replyCount, tweet.user.username])
        tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(tweets_list2, columns=('tweet', 'tweet id', 'likeCount', 'retweetCount', 'replyCount', 'username'))
        tweet_df.head()
```

the problem with the second method is that after the list gets appended. I can't access the values(eg. tweet.content) so I can insert them into the database. I've tried every method under the sun but I'm failing miserably can somebody help.

Comment: This is just a repeat of this [can't adapt type 'Gif'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159717/im-getting-a-psycopg2-programmingerror-cant-adapt-type-gif-when-i-try-to) and my comment there still applies.

Comment: I removed the media field and now the problem is an index error..

Comment: And the index error message is?

Comment: I've added the error message.

Comment: That is from the Python side, somewhere you are asking for more items from a list then exist in it. Best guess is you have mismatched the parameters in the query and the values being passed in, mostly probably when you removed the media field.

Comment: when I took out the media field. I also took out one of the %s to align values with the fields. I suspect that it is the id field that is causing the indexing error  but I could be wrong.

Comment: The traceback for the `IndexError` should point you at the point in your code where this is happening. Otherwise you will need to step through your code and see when you trigger the error.